# Angular 2 RC4 Unable to use Formbuilder

Tags: angularjs, angular, formbuilder

Everytime when I try to use the formbuilder it crashes.

> Can't resolve all parameters for the FormtestComponent

When I remove the

```
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }
```

I don't get this error.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormGroup,
    FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'formtest',
    templateUrl: './app/formtest/formtest.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/formtest/formtest.component.css'],
    directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class FormtestComponent {

    myForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { } 

}
```

Bootstrapper.ts

```
import { Main } from "./main";
import { bootstrap }    from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from "@angular/forms";

bootstrap(Main, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms()
]);
```

Comment: what do you provide at `bootstrap(...)`?

Comment: Did you inject FormBuilder somewhere?

Comment: yes, I injected the FormBuilder at the top of the formtest component

Comment: I didnt see any providers tag in FormtestComponent...

Comment: What do you mean with a providers tag? I have tried to add providers: [FormBuilder] to my Component, but that doesn't work.

Comment: The code you posted seems correct. You can compare it with this: http://plnkr.co/edit/uiYZkEWMyXWOkglHZu6N. There must be something else.

Comment: I compared every single line, I even copied the references from systemjs.config.js and the index.html but I still got the same error: 

"Can't resolve all parameters for the FormtestComponent."

I have absolutely no idea what the problem is.